# ZF2 ServiceManager is unable to create doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I get the following error, when I try to use doctrine 2 in ZF2.

> Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default

The needed modules are included and activated.

**doctrine.config.local.php**

```
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
                'params' => [
                    'host' => 'localhost',
                    'port' => '3306',
                    'user' => 'root',
                    'password' => 'password',
                    'dbname' => 'database',
                    'charset' => 'utf8',
                    'driverOptions' => [
                        1002 => 'SET NAMES utf8'
                  ],
                ],
             ],
        ],

        'configuration' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'metadata_cache' => 'array',
                'query_cache' => 'array',
                'result_cache' => 'array',
                'hydration_cache' => 'array',

                'generate_proxies' => false,
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

**module.config.php** of Core module (/module/Core/config/module.config.php)

```
namespace Core;

return [
    'service_manager' => include __DIR__ . '/service-manager.config.php',
    'router' => include __DIR__ . '/router.config.php',
    'view_manager' => include __DIR__ . '/view-manager.config.php',
    'translator' => include __DIR__ . '/translator.config.php',
    'hydrators' => include __DIR__ . '/hydrators.config.php'
];
```

**doctrine.config.php** of Core module (/module/Core/config/doctrine.config.php)

```
return [
    'driver' => [
        __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
            'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
            'cache' => 'array',
            'paths' => [
                __DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity',
            ]
        ],
        'orm_default' => [
            'drivers' => [
                __NAMESPACE__ => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

**Factory**

```
namespace Event\Form\Fieldset\Factory;

use Event\Entity\Event;
use Event\Form\Fieldset\EventFieldset;
use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class EventFieldsetFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $formElementManager) {
        $serviceLocator = $formElementManager->getServiceLocator();
        $hydratorManager = $serviceLocator->get('HydratorManager');

        // Here I get the error!
        $objectManager = $serviceLocator->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

        $fieldset = new EventFieldset();
        $fieldset->setObjectManager($objectManager);
        $fieldset->setHydrator($hydratorManager->get('Core\Hydrator\Doctrine'));
        $fieldset->setObject(new Event());

        return $fieldset;
    }

}
```

**modules** in application.config.php

```
'modules' => [
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Core',
    'Event',
    'Inquiry'
]
```

**Stack trace**

```
Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException
```

File:

```
/src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:555
```

Message:

```
Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /src/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src/DoctrineORMModule/Service/EntityManagerAliasCompatFactory.php(44): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('doctrine.entity...')
#1 [internal function]: DoctrineORMModule\Service\EntityManagerAliasCompatFactory->createService(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'doctrineormenti...', 'Doctrine\ORM\En...')
#2 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(934): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'doctrineormenti...', 'Doctrine\ORM\En...')
#3 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(1092): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'doctrineormenti...', 'Doctrine\ORM\En...')
#4 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(634): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('doctrineormenti...', 'Doctrine\ORM\En...')
#5 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Doctrine\ORM\En...', 'doctrineormenti...')
#6 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#7 /src/module/Event/src/Event/Form/Fieldset/Factory/EventFieldsetFactory.php(22): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\En...')
#8 [internal function]: Event\Form\Fieldset\Factory\EventFieldsetFactory->createService(Object(Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill), 'eventfieldsetev...', 'Event\Fieldset\...')
#9 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(934): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill), 'eventfieldsetev...', 'Event\Fieldset\...')
#10 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(330): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'eventfieldsetev...', 'Event\Fieldset\...')
#11 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(287): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'eventfieldsetev...', 'Event\Fieldset\...')
#12 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(634): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromFactory('eventfieldsetev...', 'Event\Fieldset\...')
#13 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Event\Fieldset\...', 'eventfieldsetev...')
#14 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#15 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(161): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Event\Fieldset\...', true)
#16 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/FormElementManager/FormElementManagerTrait.php(38): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Event\Fieldset\...', Array, true)
#17 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Factory.php(111): Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill->get('Event\Fieldset\...')
#18 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/Form.php(176): Zend\Form\Factory->create(Array)
#19 /src/module/Inquiry/src/Inquiry/Form/InquiryForm.php(19): Zend\Form\Form->add(Array)
#20 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/FormElementManager/FormElementManagerV2Polyfill.php(217): Inquiry\Form\InquiryForm->init()
#21 [internal function]: Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill->callElementInit(Object(Inquiry\Form\InquiryForm), Object(Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill))
#22 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(664): call_user_func(Array, Object(Inquiry\Form\InquiryForm), Object(Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill))
#23 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Inquiry\Form\In...', 'inquiryforminqu...')
#24 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#25 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(161): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Inquiry\Form\In...', true)
#26 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-form/src/FormElementManager/FormElementManagerTrait.php(38): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Inquiry\Form\In...', Array, true)
#27 /src/module/Inquiry/src/Inquiry/Controller/Factory/InquiryControllerFactory.php(23): Zend\Form\FormElementManager\FormElementManagerV2Polyfill->get('Inquiry\Form\In...')
#28 [internal function]: Inquiry\Controller\Factory\InquiryControllerFactory->createService(Object(Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager), 'inquirycontroll...', 'Inquiry\Control...')
#29 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(934): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager), 'inquirycontroll...', 'Inquiry\Control...')
#30 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(330): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'inquirycontroll...', 'Inquiry\Control...')
#31 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(287): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createServiceViaCallback(Array, 'inquirycontroll...', 'Inquiry\Control...')
#32 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(634): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->createFromFactory('inquirycontroll...', 'Inquiry\Control...')
#33 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(597): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('Inquiry\Control...', 'inquirycontroll...')
#34 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(530): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create(Array)
#35 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(161): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Inquiry\Control...', true)
#36 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(94): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Inquiry\Control...')
#37 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#38 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(490): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#39 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(263): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#40 /src/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#41 /src/public/index.php(15): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#42 {main}
```

Comment: What about the database connection details are they correct?

Comment: Hard to say why you get this error without more context. Please show the factory code where you get this error and your application.config.php

Comment: Yes sorry, I had to hurry up yesterday, so I could not add some source code. Now I added it.

Comment: Please, add all the stacktrace to your post

Comment: also the `modules` key of your `application.config.php`

Comment: I added both. In the meantime the factory is in the module "Event" instead of "Core". But the error is still the same and nothing else changed. The doctrine configuration of the event module looks like the one in the core module.

Comment: The issue could be somewhere you haven't pasted; can you export a minimalistic reproduction of it into a GitHub project?

Comment: Hey @Saeven, I created a git repo under the following url: [https://github.com/barannd/doctrine-error]. In the IndexController of the Core Module I try to get the EntityManager from the ServiceLocator. That's the point where the error occurs. I removed all other files for overview. Thanks for any help!

Comment: You give it a shot? Curious to see how things pan out for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First trouble is your config loader. You've modified it to contain:

```
    'config_glob_paths' => [
        'config/autoload/local/{,*.}local.php',
        'config/autoload/global/{,*.}global.php'
    ],
```

But your folders are set as:

config/autoload/global/doctrine.php

So the loaders won't match.

This glob path would work for your file structure:

```
    'config_glob_paths' => [
        'config/autoload/local/{,*.}php',
        'config/autoload/global/{,*.}php'
    ],
```

As alternative, I've uploaded a more 'standard' config setup that could help you:

https://github.com/Saeven/doctrine-error/tree/master/src/config

In short though, you were getting bad errors, because no connection could be established, simply because your DB details were absent (because your config loader was hosed).

Second, looks like your composer.json is loading in some incompatible items.  I used one from a project I maintain and combined with the loader fix, I see "test" when I put valid DB creds:

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",

  "minimum-stability": "dev",

  "require": {
      "php": ">=5.3.3",
      "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "@stable",

      "zendframework/zend-config": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-console": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-test": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-crypt": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-mail": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-text": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-serializer": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-mvc": "2.5.3",
      "zendframework/zend-filter": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-db": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-view": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-form": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-validator": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-i18n": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-log": "@stable",
      "zendframework/zend-cache": "@stable",

      "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.8.0",
      "doctrine/orm": "2.5.*@dev"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Saeven, indeed the configuration of my autload directory is wrong. But that wasn't the main problem. As you said , the composer.json file has loaded some incompatible items, but I don't really understand why? Doesn't matter, with your required items, everything works fine! Thank you so much for your time, cloning my repo, etc...

Comment: It's my pleasure, and hey, I'll do anything for a good bounty! ;)  Good luck with ZF2 -- ZF3 is just around the corner too!  Also, I noticed in your skeleton that you were running into the ServiceLocator warning. I have a blog post that might help you here: http://circlical.com/blog/2016/3/9/preparing-for-zend-f

Comment: Thanks but the call of the servicelocator that way was just to show the error. I don't do that normally :)

Comment: No probs, check out the lazy factory though -- it's a big help!  Did you want me to revise my answer to lock that bounty down? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in your factory and how you get the EntityManager.

Here is how to get `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` from `serviceLocator` in a ZF2 factory :

```
class YourFactory implements FactoryInterface  
{

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) 
    {            
        /* @var $em \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
        $em = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator()->get('em');

        // $em contains methods to get repo, etc ...

        // injections here
        $obj = new Obj();
        $obj->setEntityManager($em);

        return $obj;
    }

}
```

Try that and let me know

Comment: No that's not the problem. The registered service names of the entity manager is `doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default` and `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager` should be an alias of that service.

Comment: Could you help a ZF2 noob here, please? I have no idea where should I put this factory file, and how to tell ZF2 to load it. Could you add a bit more detail?

Comment: @JohnYeates this factory (dummy) is an example. Any factory must be declared in service manager, through the config file, in the `factories` section. Please read the doc at https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.service-manager.quick-start.html